# How to set an icon for the List object in Apple's Reminder app programmatically?

Tags: swift, eventkit

I know that List objects in Apple's Reminder app are in-fact EKCalendar objects as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727160/create-a-reminder-list-which-can-hold-your-reminders-in-the-reminders-app-that-y). I can access List's title property and rename the List as I wish. However, I don't see a way to set or select an icon, although icon selection is there in the actual Reminder app, they can be selected from a set of existing icons.

```
let calendar = EKCalendar(for: .reminder, eventStore: eventStore)
calendar.title = "Board game meetings" // listName
calendar.icon //no such thing as icon property available?
```

So is there a way to get an icon set on a reminder List object?